# No se despliega teclado al tocar input

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

Estoy con una  app realizada en android studio ( java ) que al salir y volver a ingresar a la misma ya no funciona que se muestre el teclado en pantalla. Sucede en varios lados de la activity, que tiene varios fragment adentro. Si se desinstala la app y se vuelve a instalar, a veces funciona a la primera vez y otras no

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_listado_buscador"
            android:layout_width="341dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:hint="Buscador"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_button_maps"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_map_24" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_listado"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```